# Postgres : create function in a particular database

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

**Code :**

```
CREATE FUNCTION square_num(num integer)
 RETURNS INTEGER AS $$

BEGIN

 IF (num<0) THEN
 RETURN 0;
 END IF;

 RETURN num*num;

END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

The above code created a function in the database `postgres` and schema `public`. How can I create a function in a particular database and it's schema? Thanks.

Comment: You have a schema for a database, without specifing a schema you will use 'public' schema provided by postgres. I suggest to create a specific schema for your database owner and create your funciton. In the end alter your function with the scheama created to the owner of the database understand?

Comment: you mean alter my function's owner to the schema of the particular database?? Is there no way I can specify the database name while creating the function??

Comment: Each function belongs to a schema

Comment: okay so there is no way I can specify the schema of a particular database. Only altering the function's owner is a way?

Comment: You can alter the schema doing ALTER FUNCTION square_num(num) SET SCHEMA your_schema_name;

Comment: To alter your function owner do ALTER FUNCTION your_schema_name.square_num() OWNER TO your_user;

Comment: `ALTER FUNCTION square_num(num integer) SET SCHEMA your_schema_name;` This seems to be working if the schema is in same database. I have the schema in a different database.

Comment: Create one schema for your database

Comment: What do you mean by that?? In my above comment I mean that if the new schema is in the `postgres` table it works for altering. I want the whole function to be moved to a different schema of a different database and not `postgres`.

Comment: connect to the database you want to ceate a fn() in, and just create it (optionally drop fn() in postgres database. this would be the process to "move" it accross db

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The above code created a function in the database postgres and schema
>   public.

No. It creates function in the database you are connected to in a first existing schema from `search_path`.

Example:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql t
psql (10.1)
Type "help" for help.

t=# create table tt();
CREATE TABLE
t=# select table_catalog,table_schema from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'tt';
 table_catalog | table_schema
---------------+--------------
 t             | public
(1 row)
```

I defined database name **t** on connection, so relation is created in database t. I don't have schema *postgres*,so `$user` was skipped, next "default" schema is `public`:

```
t=# show search_path;
   search_path
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)
```

so now:

```
t=# create schema postgres;
CREATE SCHEMA
t=# create table tt();
CREATE TABLE
```

see - no error that relation already exists, because:

```
t=# select table_catalog,table_schema from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'tt';
 table_catalog | table_schema
---------------+--------------
 t             | public
 t             | postgres
(2 rows)
```

function creation follows same rules, I used table as shorter syntax...

reading: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH

> The first schema in the search path that exists is the default
>   location for creating new objects.

finally answering

> How can I create a function in a particular database and it's schema?

connect to needed database and either explicitely specify schema name:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_schema.square_num(...and so on
```

or adjust `search_path` to meet your needs

**update** for sake of clarity I used schema name *postgres* to comply with original post. both using postgres database and creating postgres schema can be confusing for new users. There is nothing special (or system) about the default *postgres* database (that can be recreated any time from template), neither the name *postgres* gives any special attributes to schema. I only used it for OP to easier reproduce the example (as clearly from the fact that he connect to postgres database, user probably did not specify database name, connecting as OS user *postgres*). Thus to demonstrate how `search_path` first value `$user` was picked up, I used same name as username ...

Comment: I am just speechless for this answer. A very crystal-clear explanation. Thanks a lot. You clarified some more questions with your answer. just one edit in the answer - The second time you create the table it's `ii()`, change it to `tt`.

Comment: Personally I would choose a different name for the newly created schema. `postgres` might confuse novice users.(because they could think it is somehow special or reserved or akeyword, which it is not in this case)

Comment: I have chosen it as seen that OP connects as postgres user, so it would be clear that `$user` is postgres users schema

Comment: I do think that connecting as user=postgres is a bad habit (for new users). Also, the decouping of system<-->postgres usernames should be stipulated,  IMO.

Comment: I totally support such opinion. But will keep from overwriting the whole post, as it would loose its laconic outfit. I'll update it with NB instead. Thank you for your notice